# Docker - Bad Gateway when attempting to proxy nginx container to laravel php-fpm container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I'm trying to work out whats causing a 502.

I have a simple application with two containers:

`web` - running nginx, with a proxy to app: fastcgi_pass app:9000;

`app` - running php-fpm. I'm not sure how I can pass requests from web but on app/locally if I run `php artisan up` I get a response of `Application is already up.`

I can also ping `app` from `web`
`apt-get update && apt-get install iputils-ping -y && ping app`

If I attempt to visit artery.local in a browser I can see `web` in the docker logs write

> web  | 2021/11/29 21:55:33 [error] 31#31: *9 recv() failed (104:
> Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
> client: 172.18.0.1, server: artery.local, request: "GET /admin/home
> HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.2:9000", host: "artery.local"

Please can someone help me shed some light on this. I'm not sure what I can do to test that app/php-fpm is listening correctly to requests forwared by web/nginx.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  # The app
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./app-dev.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
#    ports:
#     - 9000:9000
    environment:
      - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
    networks:
      - app-network

  # A Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./web.dockerfile
    container_name: web
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

app-dev.dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get upgrade -y; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
            curl \
            libmemcached-dev \
            libz-dev \
            libpq-dev \
            libjpeg-dev \
            libpng-dev \
            libfreetype6-dev \
            libssl-dev \
            libwebp-dev \
            libmcrypt-dev \
            libonig-dev; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ libgmp-dev libpng-dev pdftk graphviz
RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get install libpcre++-dev -y
RUN pecl install oauth
RUN docker-php-ext-enable oauth

#mysql & gd 
RUN set -eux; \
    # Install the PHP pdo_mysql extention
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql; \
    # Install the PHP gd library
    docker-php-ext-configure gd \
            --prefix=/usr \
            --with-jpeg \
            --with-webp \
            --with-freetype; \
    docker-php-ext-install gd; \
    php -r 'var_dump(gd_info());'

RUN apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y libzip-dev \
     && docker-php-ext-install zip

# Curl
RUN apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev -y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN printf "\n" | pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick
RUN pear install PHP_CodeSniffer

# PHP REDIS EXTENSION
RUN printf "\n" | pecl install -o -f redis \
    &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Install XDebug
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

COPY laravel.ini /etc/nginx/conf.d/laravel.conf
COPY ./xlaravel.pool.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/laravel-pool.conf

COPY laravel.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
COPY ./xlaravel.pool.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install iputils-ping -y

# get composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

web.dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

laravel.pool.conf

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 0.0.0.0:9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
catch_workers_output = yes
request_terminate_timeout = 600
```

vhost.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name artery.local;

    root /var/www/public;

    # avoid 413 errors when uploading files up to 5M in size
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158917/laravel-app-with-nginx-proxy-refuses-connection-and-times-out)?

Comment: It is, although I thought I had deleted it. Tried to stop it down and worked forward a bit to where I think the issue is

Comment: @miken32 have removed it. Can you offer any pointers/suggestions to how I can debug this?

Comment: This is not a programming question; it's about configuring Docker so your 2 containers can communicate? You might have better luck at [sf] or [su]. Are you opening port 9000 on app container? Looks like it's commented out.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time Miken. I will post it there. I've tried with the ports uncomented with no change in behaviour.

Comment: No idea about Docker, if this were a normal server I'd suggest checking port 9000 is open using `ss -lnt` on the app server, and then checking firewalls.

Comment: thank you @miken32 I will look into that now. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the content of your nginx configuration file? The vhost.conf file

Comment: @Edgar I've updated the question. Thank you for your time. This is loaded in the web.dockerfile

Comment: @Edgar any thoughts on this? I've spent hours trying to figure this out. Even some pointers on what else I can check would be great.

Comment: @atoms, using the files you've posted here, I get a laravel site running. The only steps I'm skipping are the installation of xdebug and the COPY laravel.ini /etc/nginx/conf.d/laravel.conf. Can you try removing the containers and the images and force building the images without using the docker cache?

Comment: @Edgar eternally greatful for your time on this. You were spot on. There were two issues, the copy laravel.ini was messing with the nginx config and wasn't required. The breaking change was the xdebug include. I'm still investigating what exactly it was but I believe it was trying to auto start a connection to a debugger. Thank you. If I can buy you a beer let me know.